# python unittest of method with paho MQTT publish function inside

Tags: python, unit-testing, mqtt

Unfortunatly I can not show any code snippets yet, because I have still some basic problems to understand how to design such a testcase:

I want to test a method of a class which gets the client of a paho MQTT instance. The method is sending a mqtt message. I want to test on the content and the topic of this message.

To create a connected client to a test mqtt broker is not the problem. The outgoing message is sent. I can subscribe on this testtopic, too. But how can I test for the incoming message? This event is calling a callback function and this function is seperated from the method of the testcase which is calling the method which creates and sends the mqtt message (and also contains the assertEqual expression). Perhaps a callback on the method of the testcase and check for the *args?

Thanks in advance!